# set array as an object properties

Tags: java, arrays

i don't know how to set a specific array (with values of lets say `{1,2,3,4}`)  as an object  property?
(this is the only  property)

i tried this in my class as a constructor
(and i don't want to use initializing constructor)

```
public class Arrays {

    public int [] arr = {2,3,4,5};

    public Arrays (int[] arr ) {

        this.arr = arr; }
```

but what do i put in the brackets ?

```
Arrays a = new Arrays ();
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
Arrays a = new Arrays(int[x]{1,2,3,4,5});
```

Hope i could help you.

sexyboy

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
MyArrays arrays = new MyArrays(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must make new instance in place where you call your constructor.

```
Arrays a = new Arrays (new int[]{1,2});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the object to initialize its own array:

```
public class Arrays {
    public int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Arrays a = new Arrays();
```

If you want the caller to initialize an array and pass it to the constructor:

```
public class Arrays {
    public int[] arr;
    public Arrays(int[] arr) {
        this.arr = arr;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
Arrays a = new Arrays(arr);
```